# React useContext return undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem with context, context api return to me `undefined` value.

Here is my code :

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const authContext = createContext();

export default authContext;
```

authContext.js

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import authContext from "./authContext";
import authReducer from "./authReducer";

const authState = () => {
  const initState = {
    authValidte: false,
    authToken: null,
    authId: null,
  };
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initState);
  return (
    <authContext.Provider
      value={{
        authValidte: state.authValidte,
        authToken: state.authToken,
        authId: state.authId,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </authContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default authState;
```

authState.js

Component who want to use context :

```
...
import authContext from "./context/auth/authContext";

function App() {
  const AuthContext = useContext(authContext);
  console.log(AuthContext); // undefined
...
```

Comment: How is app component rendered and how and where is authState rendered

Comment: I don't use authState, where should I use it?

Comment: I know, authState is a wrapper for index.js component.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that custom component should be Uppercased (`AuthState`, `AuthContext.Provider` etc.).

For `authContext` to be available in `App` it must be a child of `AuthContext.Provider`. Read about [Context in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

```
<AuthState>
 <App/>
</AuthState>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for your `App Component` to use context, you need to render the `authState provider` higher up in the hierarchy of App component

Ideally it should be the common parent of all the components that may need to use it.

Also note that your component names must start with `upperCase` characters
index.js

```
import AuthState from '/path/to/authState.js'

export default () => (
   <AuthState>
      <App/>
   <AuthState>
)
```